# MSXML Сохранить изменения документа

Tags: c++, xml, com

Почему не сохраняются внесенные изменения XML документа?

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr xmlDoc;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr node;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr nodeList;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMAttributePtr nodeAtt;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNamedNodeMapPtr nodeMap;
CoInitialize(NULL);
xmlDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);

xmlDoc->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
xmlDoc->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
xmlDoc->resolveExternals = VARIANT_FALSE;

if (xmlDoc->load(ConfigFile))
{
    nodeList = xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName(Section);
    for (long i = 0; i < nodeList->Getlength(); i++)
    {
        node = nodeList->Getitem(i);
        nodeMap = node->Getattributes();
        nodeAtt = nodeMap->getNamedItem(TypeAtt);

        if (nodeAtt->Gettext().GetBSTR() == ft_Number)
        {
            nodeList = node->GetchildNodes();

            for (long n = 0; n < nodeList->Getlength(); n++)
            {
                node = nodeList->Getitem(n);

                if (node->GetnodeName().GetBSTR() == Node)
                {
                    node->Puttext(nVal.AllocSysString());
                    xmlDoc->save(ConfigFile);
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

CoUninitialize();
```

Спасибо

Comment: Где не сохраняются? Пройтись отладчиком?

Comment: Вопрос решен, нужно было установить свойство `async` в `TRUE`

Comment: Весьма странное решение. ;-)

Comment: Файл подгружается для чтения на момент инициализации диалога, после выполнения OnOK, сохраняет внесенные изменения. Получается асинхронная обработка документа.